# Convert list derived from JSON to data.table or time series

Tags: r, json, data.table

I have a .json file that I manage to load with the jsonlite library (thanks to this forum) but I cannot convert it to a single data.table which I would like to convert to a time series afterwards. These are daily sales figures for 101 products (e.g. carpeta, carpetb) for each day of this year (2020-05-11 00:00, all the day to 2020-01-01 00:00).

I would like to have a column for the date (2020-01-01) and then 101 columns, one for each product.

Here a part of the JSON-file with

```
{"results":{"carpeta":{"2020-05-11 00:00":25.18,"2020-05-10 00:00":21.30,"2020-05-09 00:00":18.65,...},"carpetb":{"2020-05-11 00:00":0.43,...}},"ts":"2020-05-11 14:08"}
```

I use

```
> library(jsonlite)
> sales <- fromJSON("sales.json")
> summary(sales)
        Length Class  Mode     
results 101    -none- list     
ts        1    -none- character

> summary(sales$results)
                          Length Class  Mode
carpeta                   133    -none- list
carpetb                   133    -none- list
...

> summary(sales$results$carpeta)
                 Length Class  Mode   
2020-05-11 00:00 1      -none- numeric
2020-05-10 00:00 1      -none- numeric

> str(sales$results$carpeta)
List of 133
 $ 2020-05-11 00:00: num 36.4
 $ 2020-05-10 00:00: num 44.7
```

Now I am stuck getting this into a data.table as the simple x <- data.table(sales$results) gives me a very long list but no structure (dates in 1 column and the 101 products in columns next to the date).

```
date       carpeta carpetb ...
2020-01-01  23.3    17.4
2020-01-02  12.7     5.4
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following **code**.

```
sales <- fromJSON("Test.json")
A = sales %>% 
    tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
    tidyr::unnest_wider(results) %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
```

**Output**

```
           rowname               V1               V2
1 2020-05-11 00:00            25.18             0.43
2 2020-05-10 00:00             21.3             <NA>
3 2020-05-09 00:00            18.65             <NA>
4               ts 2020-05-11 14:08 2020-05-11 14:08
```

**Explanation**.

Here, `Test.json` contains the bit of data that you shared. Then we convert it to a `tibble`. The central step is to use `unnest_wider` in order to deal with the lists that are contained in the columns after reading in the data. Next, we transform it in order to get the rownames as columns with the dates. Columns are then easily renamed and you can delete the last row if needed.

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Close; it nicely creates those 101 columns but the date shows up as an attribute, not a column.
`> str(A$V1)
 Factor w/ 113 levels "  0"," 0"," 0.0",..: 96 110 103 84 94 86 68 65 107 113 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:133] "2020-05-11 00:00" `

Comment: When `V1` is the `rownames` column in my code, try `as.Date(A$V1)`. Does that work? Maybe you could post a more complete dataset?